# Имеет ли класс несколько ответственностей, если содержит один публичный метод?

Tags: ооп, solid

К примеру есть класс репозитория, который ходит в REST API, получает JSON и парсит его в нужную структуру, затем данные кладет в кэш (пусть это будет SQLite). По факту у меня в репозитории один метод, например:

```
Message[] getMessages(int offset, int count)
```

Так вот, вроде как бы и одна обязанность, но как воспринимать тот факт, что в реализации этого метода класс может ходить в Http, Знает про формат данных и умеет парсить Json, а еще знает, что существует кэш с разными правилами для каждого метода, и в него нужно что-то там класть.

Как поступать с такими методами? Даже если я спрячу доступ к Http и парсинг с кэшем за дополнительными абстракциями, это не скроет тот факт, что репозиторий все же знает, про метод получения, что полученые данные надо парсить и кэшировать. По факту мне придется трогать репозиторий если изменится доступ к данным, например с Http, на Sqlite, если поменяется формат данных с json на xml, или вообще на Cursor из Sqlite, или мне потребуется выпилить кэш.

Нарушается или нет принцип SRP здесь?

Comment: смотря как все это реализовано. Если кэш создаете и сохраняете в нем сами, то скорее всего нарушается, если же вся работа с кэшем у вас сводится к передачи данных какому-то объекту, то скорее всего всего не нарушается. Надо смотреть на это так: если надо будет изменить кэш с одного на другое - класс (или его родителей) придется менять? Если придется, значит принцип нарушается, если не придется (т.е. кэш получен откуда-то извне), значит не нарушается. При этом фабричный метод не надо считать нарушением этого принципа

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Интерфейс SRP не нарушает. Реализация - нарушает. Надо прятать ответственности за абстракциями.

Насколько я понимаю, у вас основные затруднения вызывает вот этот пункт:

> Даже если я спрячу доступ к Http и парсинг с кэшем за дополнительными абстракциями, это не скроет тот факт, что репозиторий все же знает, про метод получения, что полученые данные надо парсить и кэшировать.

Нет никакой проблемы в том, что класс знает что ему надо делать. Проблема лишь в том, что он делает это сам. Если вы спрячете разные этапы за абстракциями, эти ответственности уйдут из класса в абстракции.

Comment: Т.е. в обязанности класса входит работа с кэшем, Http и Json. Как они работают классу по-барабану, все нормально. Но, смущает тот факт, что если Json заменится на Xml, то изменения затронут класс репозитория. Либо если мы изменим Http на Sqlite, уже другое изменение затронет класс репозитория.

Comment: *Если вы спрячете разные этапы за абстракциями* - здесь про родителей говорится? Так если нам надо будет изменить работу с тем же кэшем? Менять родителя плохо, значит придется менять текущий класс и тогда все спрятанное вылезет наружу? Тогда почему это не является нарушением?

Comment: @АлексейМальченко делайте абстракции так, чтобы не пришлось менять класс репозитория при смене формата.

Comment: @АлексейМальченко на то они и абстракции.

Comment: @BOPOH где я говорит про родителей?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, так я про это и спрашивал: абстракции - это родители? Или это другие классы? Ваш ответ я понял так: `class A { ...cache_logic... }; class B extends A { ...http_logic... }; class C { ...some_logic... }`. Т.е. класс C работает только с тем ("вроде только с тем"), с чем необходимо, а все остальное скрыто от него. Поэтому коммент и написал. Если имеются ввиду другие классы, то, возможно, стоит об этом написать явно, чтобы и у других сомнений не было (т.к. автора, скорее всего, это уже смутило)

Comment: @PavelMayorov как я могу абстрагироваться от формата, будь то Json, Xml или курсор Sqlite? В двух первых случаях это строки, и впринципе можно еще, но вот если я хочу распарсить данные из курсора, как быть?

Comment: @АлексейМальченко, абстрагироваться можно, если класс ничего не знает откуда он получает данные. Т.е. есть какой-то объект, у которого есть метод `get()`, вы этот метод и используете. А что происходит внутри этого объекта вам уже не интересно. Тогда этот объект может брать данные с файла, по сети, с базы или откуда-то еще, а вы пользуетесь результатом его работы. Сам объект можно получать, например, через конструктор, через какой-либо метод, либо через фабричный метод

Comment: Абстрагироваться от конкретной реализации можно с помощью делегатов, интерфейсов, абстрактного класса, причем разными способами (по числу порождающих паттернов). Или с помощью метода-хелпера в классе утилит.

Comment: @BOPOH, этим объектом с методом Get является репозиторий. Интересует реализация внутренностей этого метода. Особоно, когда все может измениться.

Comment: @АлексейМальченко парсите строку или массив байт. Не надо заниматься переусложнением задачи -  я с трудом представляю себе использование SqLite для запроса к серверу. Но даже в этом случае - что вам мешает положить в нужную колонку строку и парсить ее?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, если я начну использовать БД, то это не значит, что в ней я буду хранить строки в json формате )))

Comment: @АлексейМальченко но в таком случае у вас изменится алгоритм целиком - вам не нужны будут раздельные транспорт и формат, да и кэш будет уже не нужен.

Comment: @АлексейМальченко в таком случае вы перепишите репозиторий, а старые абстракции выкините в топку. Не надо пытаться "натянуть" абстракцию на неподходящий случай применения.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, логично, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Лучше разбить это на несколько классов:

- если нужно поменять что-то одно, придётся проверять, не поломалось ли что-то другое
- очень сложно написать тесты: надо или писать много кода, или тестировать мало граничных вариантов
- классы для работы с кешом, скачивания и распарсивания данных с других сервисов могут пригодиться и для других задач

По поводу SRP, Роберт Мартин сказал: **"A class should have only one reason to change."**
В принципе, можно сказать, что это одна причина, но, если быть с собой откровенным, то понятно, что это не так.
Я обычно задаю вопрос: "Если вынести эту логику отдельно, станет ли проще написать правильно тесты?"